# Next Js 13 'use client' post request

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

Next JS 13 in client component bellow code in try block after successful axios.post request not proceeding to setNotification callback function means stops immediately after executing  post request.

for instance in catch block first runs console.log and after setNotification callback

how to fix try block in order to make setNotification callback runs after post request ?

```
'use client';

import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function Contacts() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState('');

   const resetForm = () => {
     setName('');
     setEmail('');
    setMessage('');
   };

  async function addContactHandler(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newContact = {
      name,
      email,
      message,
    };

    try {
      await axios.post('/api/contacs', newContact);
      setNotification('ok');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Fetching failed');
      setNotification('error');
    }
  }
```

Next JS 12 same function in client component works perfectly well.

Comment: Can you show the hole component please?